# how to logout the facebook from android app

Tags: android, facebook, logout

I am following [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/) tutorial for integrating Facebook SDK for Android. It works perfectly. My problem is that what if I want to log out of the Facebook (like closing the session). How to do log in and log out on same Button.

```
 button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                     startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Following is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private Button button1;

   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(user!=null){
                    TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
                    tv1.setText("Hello "+user.getName()+ ";");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

}

 @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

     }
```

I want to log in and log out on `buttonClick`. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the SDK documentation?

Comment: yes..i have checked it..but how to put log out

Answer (score 0):

Call this method.you will logout from the session

```
 session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
```